# Extending Laravel 5.1 Mess Detection the right way

Tags: oop, design-patterns, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, php-5.6

Laravel 5.1 has only one built-in hardcoded Mess Detection, it searches to see if @package tag is the same with /namespace, like so:

```
preg_match('/namespace\ ' . self::REQUIRED_NAMESPACE . '\\\(.*);/isU', $content, $namespace);
        preg_match('/\/*( )+@package\ (.*)[\r?\n]/isU', $content, $package);

        if (!isset($namespace[1]) || empty($namespace[1])) {
            continue;
        }
```

I want to extend this to add multiple detection classes.
My folder structure currently looks like this:

```
Helpers >
    Commands >
        MessDetector >
            Detector >
                DetectorInterface.php
                DetectorAbstract.php
            PackageTagDetector.php
        MessDetector.php
```

The file MessDetector is made as an Artisan Command, that means it extends **\Illuminate\Console\Command**

I have a config file called **mess_detection.php** which has the detection rules like so:

```
return [
    'rules' => [
        '\Helpers\Commands\MessDetector\PackageTagDetector' =>
            [
                'rule' => '/\/*( )+@package\ (.*)[\r?\n]/isU',
                'path' => app_path(),
                'info' => 'Checking for @package tag',
                'error'=> 'Malformed or missing package tag'
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

But got stuck with figuring out how exactly to instantiate PackageTagDetector class in MessDetector class.

Any ideas design pattern wise?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has no built in mess detector.
Also checking if package tags matches the namespace is a custom convention, Laravel doesn't use package tags at all.
It seems like you are using a third party library?

Answer (score 0):

I have made an abstract class and interfaces for every rule I needed.
Each rule had it's own class.
The rules extended the abstract and in the abstract most of the logic was used.
The rules themselves where stored in a config file, in the config file I also mentioned the class and class specific actions.